# why muset set freertos priority group to group_4?

Tags: freertos

I am developing on freertos and one thing confusing me is that why it is suggest that "**assign all the priority bits to be preempt priority bits, leaving no priority bits as subpriority bits**"?

Could anyone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer this. It might help:

http://embeddedgurus.com/state-space/2014/02/cutting-through-the-confusion-with-arm-cortex-m-interrupt-priorities/

Answer (score 1):

This is explained on the following page: http://www.freertos.org/RTOS-Cortex-M3-M4.html  -  search for the word 'group'.

Comment: It really helps, I think I can understand it now.